# Select list t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this code:

```
select top 3 
    w.firstName, 
    w.lastName, 
    w.fbId, 
    w.idNumber, 
    w.address, 
    w.phoneNumber, 
    q.userId, 
    c.codeVal,  
    q.bidedItem, 
    SUM(q.bidCount) as sumOfBids, 
    sum(w.codesLeft + q.bidCount) as allCode
from 
    geopl_kubetiAuct.firstWeekBids as q 
join 
    geopl_kubetiAuct.Users w on q.userId = w.Id
join 
    geopl_kubetiAuct.Code c on c.userId = q.userId
where 
    q.bidedItem = 'GalaxyTabs' 
group by 
    w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, w.idNumber, 
    w.address, w.phoneNumber, q.bidedItem, q.userId, c.codeVal
order by 
    sumOfBids desc
```

It works and selects everything **OK** but there's one problem. I want that it select all code from `geopl_kubetiAuct.Code`.

When I'm executing `join geopl_kubetiAuct.Code c on c.userId = q.userId` it retrieves only first code. How can I select list of codes?

Comment: It should retrieve one record for each code in the codes table for that userId... what do you mean it only retrieves the first code?

Comment: @GB I want that it retrieves List<Code> or something like this

Comment: Are you saying that rather than having a separate row for each code, you want ALL the codes for that user returned and displayed in a SINGLE row?

Comment: something like that. not a single row I simply want to retrieve list of these values

Comment: Can you show the data you get, vs the data you want?  Because I can't make sense of what you're asking for.  Are you asking for each user to have a row for every code, whether it exists or not?  If you could provide an example of the output your getting and the output you WANT to get, it'd be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: try to remove top 3 from your select

Comment: Plan then  result and write the code based on it. if you really need top 3 records use top or else check the conditions and rewrite the code

Answer (score 0):

Removed the `TOP 3` and added actual join types

```
SELECT w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, w.idNumber, w.address, w.phoneNumber, q.userId, c.codeVal,  q.bidedItem, SUM(q.bidCount) AS sumOfBids, sum(w.codesLeft + q.bidCount) AS allCode
FROM geopl_kubetiAuct.firstWeekBids as q 
INNER JOIN geopl_kubetiAuct.Users w on q.userId = w.Id
INNER JOIN geopl_kubetiAuct.Code c on c.userId = q.userId
WHERE q.bidedItem = 'GalaxyTabs' 
GROUP BY w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, w.idNumber, w.address, w.phoneNumber, q.bidedItem, q.userId, c.codeVal
ORDER BY sumOfBids DESC
```

However if your data isnt complete in all tables on the joins try `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, w.idNumber, w.address, w.phoneNumber, q.userId, c.codeVal,  q.bidedItem, SUM(q.bidCount) AS sumOfBids, sum(w.codesLeft + q.bidCount) AS allCode
FROM geopl_kubetiAuct.firstWeekBids as q 
LEFT JOIN geopl_kubetiAuct.Users w on q.userId = w.Id
LEFT JOIN geopl_kubetiAuct.Code c on c.userId = q.userId
WHERE q.bidedItem = 'GalaxyTabs' 
GROUP BY w.firstName, w.lastName, w.fbId, w.idNumber, w.address, w.phoneNumber, q.bidedItem, q.userId, c.codeVal
ORDER BY sumOfBids DESC
```